# If $f'(z)\neq 0, \forall z\in \mathbb{C}$, does it necessarily implies that $f$ is one-to-one?

Tags: complex-analysis

I know that if $f$ is one to one, then $f'(z)\neq 0$, but is it true in the other direction?

Comment: consider $f=\exp$?

Comment: consider $f(z) = e^z$

Comment: Thanks Mookid and Mustafa Said.

Answer (score 3):

If $f'(z)\neq 0$ it does not imply $f$ is injective, for example $f(z)=e^z$.  However by the inverse function theorem we can say that $f(z)$ is locally injective.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got it now.