# Injectivity of Holomorphic function.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be a holomorphic function on Unit disk $D$ in complex plane.

If $f'(z)$ is never zero, then it implies $f$ is $1-1$?

If we can say so, How can we show that?

Thanks!

Comment: @pGroups Thanks!

Comment: "Almost" duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/723965/if-fz-neq-0-forall-z-in-mathbbc-does-it-necessarily-implies-that-f (which is the same question for the complex plane instead of the unit disk).

Answer (score 2):

The statement is not correct. Consider $f(z)=e^{8z}$. Then $f'(z)\neq 0$  and $f(0)=f(i\pi/4)=1$.